# What does it mean to have Vin =/= Vout in a steady flow?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

For a control volume and a steady flow inside a pipe $\dot{m_{in}} =\dot{m_{out}} $  -- >$\dot{V_{in}}\rho_1 =\dot{V_{out}}\rho_2 $ so for a compressable fluid where in general $\rho_1 \ne \rho_2$ the rate of flow into the control volume is different than the rate of flow out of the control volume. But what does that physically mean? Does the pipe expand/contract to accomodate the change in volume per second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\dot V$ is volume flow rate. That, in turn, is

$$\dot V=VA$$

Where $V$ is the velocity of the stream and $A$ is the cross section of the flow . So we then have

$$ρ_{1}V_{in}A_{in}=ρ_{2}V_{out}A_{out}$$

So if $A_{in}=A_{out}$ and $ρ_{1}≠ρ_{2}$ it means the inlet and outlet velocities have to be different for steady flow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the subtle point that OP is confused on is from the end of the question "does the pipe expand/contract..." -- I think OP might be thinking of water/oil/other liquid that is assumed to be incompressible. Which obviously isn't true for real liquids or fluids and might be leading to the confusion...

Comment: @tpg2114 But isn't the OP talking about a compressible  fluid? And aren't I pointing out that the pipe (area A) doesn't have to change, just the velocity of the fluid?

Comment: I didn't say you were incorrect. I was just pointing out that for some reason op thought the pipe had to expand or contract and the only way that is needed is if density is constant. But I missed where they said the fluid is compressible... So I'm confused about their question more than I thought I guess.

Comment: @tpg2114 For what its worth, I found the question a bit confusing myself.

Answer (score 1):

No, the pipe doesn't expand or contract to accommodate it really.

It just physically means that the density changes as it goes through the control volume. 
 The control volume (which is presumably a section of pipe) should remain unchanged in size over time for the steady flow.

What happens is that the fluid density changes, so if $\rho_2 \gt \rho_1$, that means that as it flows through the pipe, the particles of the fluid get closer together.  The particles basically bunch up and slow down in the process, which allows the mass flow rate to remain constant.

Comment: The gas has expanded or contracted, not the pipe.

Comment: Isn't the particles "bunching up and slowing down" if $\rho_2 \gt \rho_1$ essentially the same as saying $V_{out}<V_{in}$ in my answer?

Comment: @BobD Yes... I just tried to word it differently to try to directly address the point about the pipe expanding/contracting.  I thought a word-based explanation might have been more what OP was looking for compared to the algebraic explanation, so I answered that way.

Comment: @JMac  Got it. Thanks.